# send questions in dm, and post answers in embed to a channel discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make it where when the user initiates the command $createprofile the bot will dm the user with the questions provided in the list, one after the other then post the answers in an embed to a specified channel. Now I have already built the list, but I am unsure of how to build in asking each question one after another, I am possibly thinking of using asyncio wait_for

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import platform

import cogs._json

class Profile(commands.Cog):

   def __init__(self, bot):
       self.bot = bot

   @commands.Cog.listener()
   async def on_ready(self):
       print("Profile Cog has been loaded\n-----")

   # @commands.command(aliases=['pm'])
   # async def dm(self, ctx, user: discord.User, *, message=None):
   #   message = message or "This message is sent via dm"
   #   await user.send(message)
   #   await ctx.message.delete()

   @commands.command()
   async def createprofile(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
       userName = ""
       userAge = ""
       questions = [
           "Please input your name/nickname:",
           "Please input your age:"
       ]
       dmChannel = await ctx.author.send(
           "You will be receiving two questions. One involving your name and the other your age.")

       def check(message):
           return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == dmChannel.channel

       async def askQuestion(question):
           await ctx.author.send(question)
           print("Waiting for reply...")
           userReply = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
           print("User replied")
           return userReply.content
           userName = await askQuestion(questions[0])
           userAge = await askQuestion(questions[1])
           e = discord.Embed(title=str(userName) + "'s Profile", description=f"""
           Age: `{str(userAge)}`
           """)
           await ctx.send(embed=e)

def setup(bot):
   bot.add_cog(Profile(bot))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@client.command()
async def createprofile(self, ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    userName = ""
    userAge = ""
    questions = [
        "Please input your name/nickname:",
        "Please input your age:"
    ]
    dmChannel = await ctx.author.send(
        "Yo will be receiving two questions. One involving your name and the other your age.")

    def check(message):
        return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == dmChannel.channel

    async def askQuestion(question):
        await ctx.author.send(question)
        print("Waiting for reply...")
        userReply = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        print("User replied")
        return userReply.content
    userName = await askQuestion(questions[0])
    userAge = await askQuestion(questions[1])
    e = discord.Embed(title=str(userName) + "'s Profile", description=f"""
    Age: `{str(userAge)}`
    """)
    await ctx.send(embed=e)
```

First, you need to send the user a question, so how you do that is through `await ctx.author.send("this is a question")`.  You then store that message into a variable. You then create a check function that makes sure that the user who replied is in fact the user who sent the `$createprofile` message in the first place. You will also need to check if the message's channel is the dm channel. So that's where the message you stored earlier takes action. It will make sure that the channel of the message is the same as the channel of the dm message you sent to the user earlier. After that, you create an async function to ask a question. From there on it's pretty straightforward. Feel free to optimize your code using `for loops`. Hope this helps.

Comment: yes but wouldnt you have to define the channel under channel = dm.channel or am I wrong on that one, and each section would actually be phrased like a question such as 
what is your name?,  what is your age? so I am trying to have it where it will ask the what is your name question first then once the user answers, it will ask the next

Comment: @JangoDarkWind feel free to ask any questions

Comment: but if i am understanding it right then the dm channel and message channel is separate, cause the main issue right now is that it sends the message "You will be receiving two questions. One involving your name and the other your age." and I reply nothing else happens. Also the original code when I ran it gave the error ctx has no attribute author, so I changed dmChannel = await ctx.author.send to dmChannel = message.author.send and it sent the dm otherwise it gane an error

Comment: Ah, you must be using the on_message event. My bad. Is it working now? Because for me it works fine.

Comment: i have updated the code in my original message with the code I put in except with the @commands.command instead of "@"client.command I should have said this command is being run under a cog. ignore the quotations

Comment: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Profile' object has no attribute 'author' this is the error provided firsthand

Comment: @JangoDarkWind In your provided sample code no object or class named "Profile" can be found, meaning nobody can help you with this error, because the relevant code is not provided. Please consider rewriting your question to contain all relevant code.

Comment: You missed a `self` in the command arguments. Change it to `async def createprofile(self, ctx, member: discord.Member = None)` @JangoDarkWind

Comment: ok, that problem is fixed, but now all it does is send the "You will be receiving two questions. One involving your name and the other your age.") then I reply and nothing else

Comment: You should've received an embed with your name and age in the channel in which you initiated the createprofile command. That's what happened for me. Oh wait, you need to change `client.wait_for` to `commands.wait_for`. Aren't these errors showing up in your IDE? If you're not using one, please do. I recommend PyCharm. These errors will then appear during compile time.

Comment: now i get this error discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
 for userReply = await commands.wait_for('message', check=check) actually managed to part of it to work I'm so proud

Comment: I do not undersrand it

Comment: Can you send me your whole file? Like the main file besides the cog file? I'll need to view it to assess the error. just edit it into your question. Again, pls download an ide. It will show you the compiling errors in your code.